# Would like to make a popup onselect/onhighlight

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm **currently** trying to make **an vscode extension**.
I would like to have an popup over a text that you are currently highlighting/that you have selected, like the screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjFfq.png).

I have tried with `vscode.languages.registerDocumentHighlightProvider` without success.

Does someone can help me ?

**PS:** Or when you highlight/select text then do an action (whatever)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection(() => { ... })`

But, how to create the popup?

Comment: Pls don't post something as solution/answer if it isn't actually one. Instead add new knowledge to your original question as an update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a popup yourself, that's not allowed in vscode. What you can do is to add items to the existing editor context menu, but that's rather static (you have to define the menu items in your package.json file).

Here is the documentation of the [menu contribution point in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus).

Comment: Could you send me an github link of an extension which is doing it, or some docs about it please ? Thanks

Comment: I added the link to the documentation.